# How to replace values in Numpy Ndarrays based on a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy multidimensional array with sequences of zeros and ones. I want to replace the zero for any sequence 101. For example:

```
a = np.array([[0,0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,0,1]])
```

should become:

```
a = np.array([[0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

k = np.array([[1,0,1]]) # kernel for convolution
a[(convolve2d(a,k,'same')==2) & (a==0)] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Using 2D convolution works for this case. Is there a way to solve this if the case changes? For example, replacing a sequence of [1,0.5, 0.5,1] with [1 0 0 1] anywhere in the ndarray.